# Display popup for specific customers or vendors - NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I apologize if this is a simple script but I am new to JavaScript/SuiteScript. I am writing a SuiteScript 2.0 script and am trying to display a popup for specific customers. The issue is Customers don't display on the Purchase Order Form, they display on the Sales Order form. In NetSuite I have the deployment script set to Purchase Orders because this popup needs to display from the Purchase Order Form. Purchase Orders are created from Sales Orders.

How do I have the script look at the Customer Field ID 'entity' on the Sales Order form through the SO # Field ID 'createdfrom' on the Purchase Order Form. The tricky part is there is a Field ID 'entity' with the label Vendor on the Purchase Order Form.

This is what I have so far but I don't have anyone here at work to teach/help me.

```
function saveRecord(context) {
    var getRec = context.currentRecord;         // to connect updated record
    var vendor = getRec.getValue('entity');     // variable for entity field

    if (context.fieldid == vendor) {            // looking at the vendor('entity') field id
        if (vendor.id == '4907') {              // vendor id i need
        dialog.alert({                          // popup
            title : 'IMPORTANT',
            message : 'Labels Required'
        });
        return true;                            // save the record
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please open browser development tool (f12), do you see any error log?

Answer (score 0):

I think `context.fieldid` will only return `undefined`.

I didn't test code below. Please try following code and let me know if this work for you.

```
function saveRecord(context) {
  var getRec = context.currentRecord;         // to connect updated record
  var vendor = getRec.getValue('entity');     // This will return internal id for this customer.

  console.log('Vendor id: ' + vendor);

  if (vendor == '4907') {              // vendor id i need
      dialog.alert({                          // popup
          title : 'IMPORTANT',
          message : 'Labels Required'
      });
      return true;                            // save the record
  }
}
```